# Redux action not firing on move with react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I'm pretty new to React and Redux and very new to react-dnd, and I think I'm doing something wildly incorrect here. Although there are other similar posts out there I can't quite find a solution in them.

I'm working on a Kanban board app that is somewhat based on the one found at https://survivejs.com/react/implementing-kanban/drag-and-drop/ though that version uses Alt.js and I'm using Redux.

The problem: when dragging a component, the action function is called but the case in the reducer (MOVE_TICKET) is not. This seems to be the case regardless of the content of the action function.

I linked the action to a click event and in this instance the action and reducer worked as expected. This leads me to think that it must be a problem with the way I've set up the Ticket component with the dnd functions.

**Ticket.js:**

```
    import React from "react" 
    import {compose} from 'redux';
    import { DragSource, DropTarget } from 'react-dnd';
    import ItemTypes from '../constants/ItemTypes';
    import { moveTicket } from "../actions/ticketsActions"


    const Ticket = ({
        connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, isDragging, isOver, onMove, id, children, ...props
    }) => {
      return compose (connectDragSource, connectDropTarget)(
        <div style={{
          opacity: isDragging || isOver ? 0 : 1
        }} { ...props } className = 'ticket'>
          <h3 className = 'summary'> { props.summary } </h3>
          <span className = 'projectName'> { props.projectName }</span>
          <span className = 'assignee'> { props.assignee } </span>
          <span className = 'priority'> { props.priority } </span>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const ticketSource = {
      beginDrag(props) {
        return {
            id: props.id,
          status: props.status
        };
      }
    };

    const ticketTarget = {
      hover(targetProps, monitor) {
        const targetId = targetProps.id;
        const sourceProps = monitor.getItem();
        const sourceId = sourceProps.id;
        const sourceCol = sourceProps.status;
        const targetCol = targetProps.status;

        if(sourceId !== targetId) {
          targetProps.onMove({sourceId, targetId, sourceCol, targetCol});
        }
      }
    };

    export default compose(
        DragSource(ItemTypes.TICKET, ticketSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
          connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
          isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        })),
        DropTarget(ItemTypes.TICKET, ticketTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
          connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
          isOver: monitor.isOver()
        }))
    )(Ticket)
```

**ticketsReducer.js:**

```
export default function reducer(state={
    tickets: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
  }, action) { 

    switch (action.type) {
      case "MOVE_TICKET": {
        return [{...state, tickets: action.payload}]

      } 
    }
    return state
}
```

**ticketsActions.js**

```
import store from '../store';


export function moveTicket({sourceId, targetId, sourceCol, targetCol}) {

    const columns = Object.assign({}, store.getState().tickets.tickets)    
    const sourceList = columns[sourceCol];
    const targetList = columns[targetCol];
    const sourceTicketIndex = sourceList.findIndex(ticket => ticket.id == sourceId);
    const targetTicketIndex = targetList.findIndex(ticket => ticket.id == targetId);

    if(sourceCol === targetCol){
      var arrayClone = sourceList.slice();
      arrayClone.splice(sourceTicketIndex, 1);
      arrayClone.splice(targetTicketIndex, 0, sourceList[sourceTicketIndex]);

      columns[sourceCol] = arrayClone;
    }

    return function(dispatch){
      dispatch({type: "MOVE_TICKET", payload: columns});
      }

}
```

**Column.js (where each Ticket component is rendered)**

```
import React from "react"
import uuid from "uuid"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import ColumnsContainer from "./ColumnsContainer"
import Ticket from "./ticket"
import { moveTicket } from "../actions/ticketsActions"

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    columns: store.columns.columns
  };
})
export default class Column extends React.Component {

    console(){
        console.log(this)
    }

    render(){

        const tickets = this.props.tickets.map((ticket, id) => 
            <Ticket 
                key = {uuid.v4()}
                id={ticket.id}
                summary = { ticket.summary }
                assignee = { ticket.assignee }
                priority = { ticket.priority }
                projectName = { ticket.displayName }
                onMove={ moveTicket }
                status= { ticket.status }
            /> 
        )

        return(
            <div key = {uuid.v4()} className = { this.props.className }>
                <h2 key = {uuid.v4()}>{ this.props.title }</h2>
                <ul key = {uuid.v4()}>{ tickets }</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong I could really use some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not connecting the `moveTicket` action to redux's dispatcher.

You'll have to do something like:

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    columns: store.columns.columns
  };
}, {moveTicket})
export default class Column extends React.Component {
// ... 
// use this.props.moveTicket instead of moveTicket
```

The second parameter to `connect` is called `mapDispatchToProps`, which will do the `dispatch(actionFn)` for you.

You might want to name the bound action differently, e.g.

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    columns: store.columns.columns
  };
}, {connectedMoveTicket: moveTicket})
// then use this.props.connectedMoveTicket
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I seem to be heading in the right direction now, but where should I connect mapDispatchToProps? after {moveTicket}, or elsewhere?